# it is secure to have a plain text password for my PostgreSQL connection in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am not sure if it is not secure to have a plain text password for my PostgreSQL database connection.

i.e

In my "**settings.py**" file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_database', # database name
        'USER': 'username',    # P.user
        'PASSWORD': 'plaintext password goes here',
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # where is locate our database?
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

If it is not secure please give more information about how to handle this situation.

**Note: I am using https for my webpage but I'm just wanna know if I have to secure this also even if the connection is locally.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not secure to keep password as a plain text in your source code. You may make your project open source and forgot to remove password from repository, or you can copy code to the SO question:) and don't remove password. So it's better to keep password and other secrets for example `SECRET_KEY` as environment variable. 
During development you can use [`python-dotenv`](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) library for this. So your settings.py file will looks like this:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_database', # database name
        'USER': 'username',    # P.user
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # where is locate our database?
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and help, I am very gratefully.

Answer (score 1):

you can use environment variables:

## set

```
os.environ["password"] = "your_password"
```

## get

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_database', # database name
        'USER': 'username',    # P.user
        'PASSWORD': os.environ["password"],
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # where is locate our database?
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```